# Getting data from similar columns but from different dynamic tables in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, information-schema

I have multiple dynamic tables like

```
{
user_details_1
user_details_2
user_details_6
user_details_9
}
```

all these tables contain same columns structure

```
{
user_id
start_date
end_date
}
```

but i have to delete all the rows of users who's end_date is lower than today.

What i need is something like this

```
{DELETE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'user_details_%'
WHERE end_date <= NOW()}
```

I need query for this purpose because above query is not working.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: _"all these tables contain same columns structure"_ Why do you have so many tables then? Please change your database schema rather than make a coding workaround for this. Just create an extra column called "`user_detail_id`" and have one table.

Comment: I need query for this purpose because above query is not working.

Comment: Matt : I have huge data like in millions records so for some reason i have to do this and above is just an example my database and tables are different.

Comment: You can use `PARTITION` if the dataset is large, but follows a certain schema

Comment: hjpotter92: We are using such tables for some other purpose. I am sorry i cannot explain the whole scenario. I have to anyhow do this through one query.